# IPRange ssh scan python

Tags: python

Is there any posibility to make my "**raw_input** - **rmip**" to accept and convert iprange(192.168.1.1/28) and then scan all iprange and ports? I tried to do that with IPset module but i have some errors.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    import socket, subprocess,sys
    import os 
    from netaddr import *

    subprocess.call('clear',shell=True)
    rmip = raw_input("\t enter your ip address: ")
    r1 = int(raw_input("\t enter start port :\t"))
    r2 = int(raw_input("\t enter end port :\t"))

for ips in IPSet([rmip]):
    try:
        for port in range(r1,r2):       
                    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
                    result = sock.connect_ex((ips, port))
                    if result == 0:
                        print "  [-] Port Open: --->\t", port
                    sock.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "You stop this "
            sys.exit()
    except socket.gaierror:
            print "Hostname could not be resolved"
            sys.exit()
    except socket.error:
            print "could not connect to server"
            sys.exit()
```

**Output:**

```
     enter your ip address: 129.1.1.1/24
     enter start port : 1
     enter end port :   4000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = sock.connect_ex((ips, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
 TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, IPAddress found
```

Comment: It wants a string, not an IPAdress

Comment: Oook, and where do I need to change to receive "string" and output iprange and then scan that range..?